# angularjs: What is the preferred way to pass data from controller to directive(s)?

Tags: angularjs

i have a Article Item page that is composed of several re-usable directives.  one section of the page has several of these directives that make the main article for the page.

```
<div data-ng-controller="ArticleItemController">
    <article-breadcrumb data-bread-crumbs="model.breadCrumbs"></article-breadcrumb>
    <article-title data-title="model.title"></article-title>

    <div id="home-main">
        <div id="post-area">
            <social-box></social-box>
            <article-content-area data-content="model.content"></article-content-area>
            <article-author-info data-author="model.author"></article-author-info>
            <article-tags data-tags="model.tags"></article-tags>
            <social-box></social-box>
        </div>

        <prev-next-article data-articles="model.prevNextArticle"></prev-next-article>
        <related-article data-articles="model.relatedArticles"></related-article>
        <comments data-comments="model.comments"></comments>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller to gets the promise, then i pass parts of model to my directives via attributes.

```
app.controller('ArticleItemController', function ($scope, genApi)
{
    $scope.model = $scope.model || {};
    genApi.Articles.get({ Id: 60 }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.model = data;
    });
});
```

but this doesn't seem to work or it's sometimey.  the only way i can see the data from the directives is if i do this and force the $apply.

```
app.directive('articleBreadcrumb', function ($timeout)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: { breadCrumbs: '=' },
        templateUrl: '/app/directives/articleItem/articleBreadcrumb/articleBreadcrumb.html',
        link: function (scope) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $timeout(function () {
                    console.log(scope.breadCrumbs);
                }, 0);
            },0);
        }
    };
});
```

what are some better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of thinking is right, indeed the best way to pass data to your directives is using attributes, or if your directive is very simple you can even inherit the data from your parent scope.

Here are 2 example directives, one for each case:

```
app.directive('myScopedDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {content: '='},
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>{{content}}</div>'};
});

app.directive('myInheritedDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>{{content}}</div>'};
});
```

And here is a working plunkr demonstrating the promise resolving:

http://plnkr.co/edit/a1MDQpjtWAfTYfLpiypC?p=preview

Hope that helps